# django rest-framework add fields to ModelSerializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have the following serializer:

```
class AMXModXAdminsSerializer(mixins.GetCSConfigMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    admin = serializers.CharField(label='Admin', max_length=35, required=True, write_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(label='Password', max_length=35, required=False, write_only=True)
    access_flags = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(choices=ACCESS_FLAGS_OPTIONS, required=True, write_only=True)
    account_flags = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(choices=ACCOUNT_FLAGS_OPTIONS, required=True, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CS16Server
        fields = ('name', 'amxadmins', 'admin', 'password', 'access_flags', 'account_flags')
        read_only_fields = ('name', 'amxadmins',)
```

When I try to access the url it complains:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `admin` on serializer `AMXModXAdminsSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `CS16Server` instance.
Original exception text was: 'CS16Server' object has no attribute 'admin'.
```

If I add write_only to each field, the error will go away.

The thing is that I have a similar serializer, for the same model, with fields which do not belong to the model and it works perfectly without adding "write_only=True" to each field.

Any idea why one would work and another one no ?

Answer (score 0):

What do u mean "when i access" ? post get put patch ?

Error says:

```
'CS16Server' object has no attribute 'admin'.
```

Does it ? if not , where do u intend to write it to ?
If model does not have admin field (as mentioned in error ) you need something like this:

```
class AMXModXAdminsSerializer(mixins.GetCSConfigMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    admin= serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    fields ...
    ...
    def get_admin(self, obj):
        do somthing with self (contains the request) or the obj you're working on 
        return theOUTcome
```

Comment: I just need it when I'm posting something, then I'll get the value and introduce it into another field


I have several fields which are not on the model, get the values, operate on them & then introduce a new value on a field which exists on the model.

Comment: The logic should enter the get_admin method.u can import other models and do whatever

Answer (score -1):

If you set required=False it will not complain anymore because it will not try to get those fields values from db.